# Have a way to intercept, through a plugin, the login event in Piwik/Matomo?

Tags: php, matomo, piwiktracker

I need intercept the login event, I have been tried through events, but not work as I have been expected.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function registerEvents()
{
    $hooks = array(
        // 'Request.initAuthenticationObject' => 'initAuthenticationObject',
        // 'API.Request.authenticate'         => 'ApiRequestAuthenticate',
        // 'Request.dispatch'                 => 'RequestDispatch'
    );

    return $hooks;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you are trying to do. There are events posted before and after the login like `Login.authenticate` and `Login.authenticate.failed`, `Login.authenticate.successful`